# Displaying loading icon if a value is not available in Angular JS

Tags: angular

I have a page in AngularJS where I am showing some data inside a variable. Now, this data often takes sometime to load, so I want that if variable is empty, I show a spinner, otherwise if variable has some value, I show the value in variable. Can I do it directly in the `div` tag?

For example:

```
  <div [hidden]="reviewable && !suggestionIsRejected" class="oppia-suggestion-review-message">
    <strong>Review message: </strong>{{ reviewMessage }}
  </div>
```

How can I Add a condition on this variable `reviewMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

Add two div tags using ng-show or ng-if

[image]

Or you can use condition inside string interpolation

[image]